# Alignment of the content in navigation page

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have created a plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/y6QeYrm6I2kcm3Jm9Us5?p=preview)

I have a main page with left navigation (`index.html`). When I click on Header details the `AddHeader.html` page should be opened. Where I have added all the files. I think I am missing out something due to which the `AddHeader.html` page is not getting perfectly fitted in the main page. When I run this in internet explorer the `AddHeader.html` page is always shown at the bottom. Please help.

I am just adding a snippet from `index.html` where I have added `ng-view`:

```
<div class="pull-right" style="margin-right:20px">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation bars are fixed, you have to set margin for the content. I have updated your code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HG1XPfUTOz2zpn67ZfBH?p=preview)

Look at `index.html` line 58, as your code above, I have removed `pull-right` and added a class `page-content` to the div and set margin for it in CSS:

```
.page-content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}
```

Comment: ur solution works perfectly in plunkr but when I run the same solution in my browser. AddHeader.html page is still displayed at the bottom

Comment: I had to re arrange the file imports...Its working now .. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a navbar on the left with `position: fixed`. You either need to float the navbar and container to the left (which probably wouldn't be desired behaviour), or account for this with a margin offset on your container:

```
.container {
    margin-left: 60px; /* Equal to the width of your navbar */
}
```

Hope this helps!